# Negative Harmonic Series?

Tags: special-functions

I was doing some work and the following expression came up in one my computations...

```
HarmonicNumber[-(\[Lambda]/\[Mu])] /. {\[Lambda] -> 0.5, \[Mu] -> 1}
-1.38629
```

Is this correct? Is there a "negative" harmonic series?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For noninteger arguments, `HarmonicNumber[]` is the same (up to an additive constant) as the [digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html):

```
HarmonicNumber[x] // FunctionExpand
   EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, 1 + x]
```

so

```
EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, 1 - 1/2] // FunctionExpand
   -Log[4]

N[%]
   -1.38629
```